# How to prevent fork from returning twice,

Tags: c

so I am working on this C code, that print a list of child PID and parent PID

the problem that my output looks like this

```
digraph {
           "12896" [ label="pid 12896, level 0" ];
    "12897" [ label="pid 12897, level 1" ];
    "12896" -> "12897";
    "12898" [ label="pid 12898, level 2" ];
    "12897" -> "12898";
    "12899" [ label="pid 12899, level 3" ];
    "12898" -> "12899";
    "12900" [ label="pid 12900, level 4" ];
    "12899" -> "12900";
}digraph {
           "12896" [ label="pid 12896, level 0" ];
    "12897" [ label="pid 12897, level 1" ];
    "12896" -> "12897";
    "12898" [ label="pid 12898, level 2" ];
    "12897" -> "12898";
    "12899" [ label="pid 12899, level 3" ];
    "12898" -> "12899";
digraph {
           "12896" [ label="pid 12896, level 0" ];
    "12897" [ label="pid 12897, level 1" ];
    "12896" -> "12897";
    "12898" [ label="pid 12898, level 2" ];
    "12897" -> "12898";
digraph {
           "12896" [ label="pid 12896, level 0" ];
    "12897" [ label="pid 12897, level 1" ];
    "12896" -> "12897";
digraph {
```

there is 4 different digraph object, I only need the first one. also I am not sure why the first line inside digraph is tabbed, if anyone knows

here is the C code of my fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void){

    int i, status;
    printf( "Enter a value for n :");
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("./diagraph.txt", "w+"); //my output file
    fprintf(file, "digraph {\n");
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++){

        //fflush(stdout);
        int pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0 ) {

                if(i == 0){ //first level
                        fprintf(file, "    \"%d\" [ label=\"pid %d, level %d\" ];\n", getppid(), getppid(), i, file);
                        fprintf(file, "    \"%d\" [ label=\"pid %d, level %d\" ];\n", getpid(), getpid(), i +1, file);
                        fprintf(file, "    \"%d\" -> \"%d\";\n", getppid(), getpid(), file);
                }else{
                        fprintf(file, "    \"%d\" [ label=\"pid %d, level %d\" ];\n", getpid(), getpid(), i +1, file);
                        fprintf(file, "    \"%d\" -> \"%d\";\n", getppid(), getpid(), file);

                }
        }
        else{ //parent process, we will wait for the children.
        pid = waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        return 0;
        }
    }

fprintf(file, "}");
fclose(file);

}
```

I am not sure of the reason of this behavior, I would like to understand it and know how to fix it
thank you in advance

Comment: Show a minimal working example of your program, not just bits. You're probably not exiting at the right spot in the child processes though.

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve]. The code can not produce the output you're discussing, so any answer relies on guessing what you did and that's bad.

Comment: Some `fflush()`'s might be called for, too.

Comment: You should call `_exit` in every process but the one that's writing to the file. Otherwise, process tasks that are supposed to take place when the process terminates will take place in unpredictable overlapping bits as each child process terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when you write to a file with `fprintf` it doesn't actually write to the file (yet) -- it just writes to a buffer.  When the buffer fills up, or you later call `fflush` or `fclose`, *then* the data in the buffer is written to the file.  The buffer is part of the FILE object stored in memory of the process, so when you call `fork`, the buffer and it's contents are duplicated.  This results in a situation where both the child and parent may write the same data into the file, resulting in duplication.

The easiest way to avoid this is to ensure you call `fflush` on all `FILE` objects you have before calling fork, so that the buffers are all empty and no data is duplicated.

Comment: That is not a reliable way to fix it though. It may happen to work on some platforms, but it's definitely not guaranteed to work and that may not be the only such issue with work being done by the child process at termination that the parent process does not expect to have happen early or more than once.

Answer (score 0):

While a process is executing, it may need to arrange to have a number of tasks performed when that process terminates. When you call `fork`, the child process inherits this arrangement from the parent. If the child process terminates normally, it will execute this list of tasks.

In general, there is no way for someone writing application code to know what's on this list. It's managed by system libraries and can contain very platform-dependent things. In this case, it's flushing standard library buffers to the file.

It is extremely important that you not let both a parent process and a child process terminate normally unless you have some way to know that this duplication of possible exit tasks created in the parent will not cause a problem. Serious bugs involving significant compromises to security-sensitive information have occurred because this has been ignored.

The simplest solution is to ensure that all processes but the initial one terminate by calling `_exit`. If you write to any streams in the child, you need to `fflush` them before the `fork` and `fclose` them in any child that used them before calling `_exit`.

You can, and should, use `fflush` if a stream is going to be accessed in both the parent and the child processes. But don't think that just because you called `fflush` that means it's safe to let the child terminate normally. There is no way to know (without looking closely into the particular platform's standard library implementation) what that will do.

Comment: Problem is, if you call `_exit` (without first calling `fflush`), you lose all the output from the child process that is intended to happen...

Comment: @ChrisDodd To fix that case, you need to call `fclose` in the child and you still need to call `_exit`. I added that.